# incrementing and decrementing stepper in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistepper

I am trying to append/remove an element to an array when my stepper is pressed. It is possible to accomplish this using temp variables and if statements, but is there a more simple way to access whether the stepper was incremented or decremented?

Comment: Please share some code what you already tried

Comment: Can't you just compare the stepper value against the array `count` and then you know whether the user stepped up or down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare the length of your array to `sender.value` in stepper changed function

Answer (score 2):

You could use a switch statement inside of an @IBAction attached to your stepper like so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        testStepper.minimumValue = -1.0
        testStepper.maximumValue = 1.0
        testStepper.value = 0
        testStepper.autorepeat = false
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var testStepper: UIStepper!

    @IBAction func testStepperHandler(_ sender: Any) {
        switch testStepper.value {
            case 1.0:
                // add your item here
                print("Item added")
                testStepper.value = 0

            default:
                // remove your item here
                print("Item removed")
                testStepper.value = 0

        }
    }

}
```

Even though there is no direct way to access whether a stepper has been incremented or decremented, we can work around this limitation by turning out stepper into a sort of "binary paddle" by constraining the properties we can access in `viewDidLoad()` : setting the minimumValue to -1.0 and `maximumValue` to 1.0 and an initial value of 0. We then need to reset the value of the stepper to 0 regardless of which path the switch statement takes. When the user increments the stepper, a value of 1 will be returned and the code in the first case will execute. Since there are only 2 values that can be returned (1.0 for increment, or -1.0 for decrement) we can just use the default to handle all other cases.